# Git Flow Confusion On Release Branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

I am trying to understand one thing in git flow. Lets assume we have branch tree like this

[image: Git Flow]

In this scenario I merged my release branch by opening a PR to master and dev separately. I merged PRs with using

```
git merge --squash
```

command. At the end of merge, I have two different commit ids

master has D1234
dev has C4567

My confusion starts here. If master and dev don‘t have the same commit hashes, in the next PR to master from release branch I will see C4567 in the PR. I had to merge an empty commit with no diff. Where am I doing mistake? How can I get same HEAD for master and dev after merge?

#### **SOLUTION : SQUASH MERGE IS NOT A MERGE**

Comment: _I merged my release branch by opening a PR to master and dev separately_ with this flow you should only open a PR to dev (optionally merge with squash) then later dev will be merged to release then master (without squash). Why 2 PRs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram is wrong. A squash merge is *not a merge*. It causes a new commit to appear out of thin air, with *no* record of how or why. If you do a squash merge to `master` and a squash merge to `dev`, master and dev are two totally independent commits, unrelated to each other and unrelated to the feature branch. So the arrows pointing from the end of the feature branch to the ends of `master` and `dev` are false and should be deleted.

If you wanted there to be some sort of *relationship* between these things, at the very least use real merges. And do not take shortcuts. Do this the normal way: PR to dev, merge to dev, *then* see about getting that (the merge commit on `dev`) onto master.

A release branch (which seems to be what you are asking about) is like a normal branch off of dev except (1) it stops all features from being merged into dev, and (2) as you rightly say, the goal here is to merge into master, though of course we must also merge back to dev. You might want to see the original document, https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, which is much simpler and clearer than the atlassian page you cited.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

According to this document we should merge release to dev and master. As far as I understand that. Do you mean something different from that document? Apart from squashing things

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about the release branch situation? But that document says nothing about open two PRs, using squash merges, or any of that stuff you did.

Comment: How do you merge release with dev and master without open two PRs?

Comment: PRs are not a git feature. Git flow is about _Git_. How you manage PRs is up to you; different dev houses have different policies for handling this.

Comment: Alright thanks. I understand now. Squashing is not merging as you said. We should use --no--ff for tracking git history. Disadvantage of it, --no-ff creates merge commit and it make master is ahead from dev vice versa.

On the other hand we can use ff for single line of git history but it will make harder to track history. Also we have to rebase if target has newer commits. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get same HEAD for master and dev after merge?

You can't. Well, *technically* you could, but you probably don't want to.

A branch in git points to a commit; that commit points to other commits, back through history. Each of those commits is identified by a unique hash; if two different commits had the same hash, everything would be horribly broken. That hash covers both the contents of the repository, and all the metadata of the commit, including what parents it has.

So if two different branches point at the same hash, those branches are identical - not just identical in their current content, but identical in their entire history.

The only way for that to happen is to always use "fast-forward" merges, everywhere, so that all your branches are actually just pointers in a single line of commits. In practice, that means rebasing things, a lot - for instance, every hotfix will probably require rebasing the whole of develop, and then rebasing all open feature branches onto that new develop.

That's a lot of work, and a lot of things that can go wrong, to avoid this:

> I had to merge an empty commit with no diff.

Git was smart enough to recognise that no actual changes were needed, even though you'd merged two unrelated commits (remember: a squash merge throws away all history on the feature branch). That is it solving the problem for you.

The other solution, as pointed out in comments, is not to merge the feature to two places in the first place. Merge release to master, and then merge master to develop.

Comment: I'd second the recommendation of not merging the hotfix to both master and develop. I'm personally of the opinion that resync with master as in the case of the hotfix should come from master. In theory apart from the hotfix changes there should be NOTHING in master that is not in develop (minus things like different configs - for those you just need to be careful). For me it's a sanity check. If master cannot be merged to develop nicely then there's something seriously wrong